# Hide or Show a Menu Item if Webview Class Activated?

Tags: android, if-statement, webview

I am trying to disable programmatically a menu item if `WebView` class is not activated.

I tried this code:

```
      @Override
      public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
      {
          super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.itemRefresh);

         if (WebViewFragment.viewContentWebView.isActivated()){

          item.setVisible(true);
          item.setEnabled(true);

          } else
              {
                item.setVisible(true);
                item.setEnabled(false);
          }
          return true;
      }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemRefresh:
                WebViewFragment.viewContentWebView.reload();
                return true;
            case R.id.itemAdd:

                //oke im gonna write here
                return true;
            case R.id.itemHelp:
                // ok ok i will
                return true;
            default: 
                return true;
            }   
        }
```

In Eclipse I don't get any error msg but on real device App blocks itself.

I think I'm doing something wrong in `IF-ELSE` statement part.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "App blocks itself"?

Comment: I mean,the app doesnt run anymore, close itself.

Comment: Can you post the logcat errors?